# How can I pass in the arguments to a function in react from within the html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am iterating through an array of objects and I want to call a function for each of the iterations with the objects properties as the arguments. When I click on the button all it does is reload the page and doesn't pass the arguments to the function because I can't see it in the console when I console.log()

```
const Posts = () => {


  const mySubmitHandler = async ( pos) => {
    console.log(pos);
    try {
      console.log(window.web3.currentProvider)
      console.log(accounts)
      const res = await snInstance.reply(pos, reply, { from: accounts[0] });
      console.log("-----------------rererer-----------------")
      console.log(res, accounts);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }

 return (
      <div>
        {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
          return <tr key={index}>
    <form onSubmit={() => mySubmitHandler(p.postsCounter)} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>

          <div style={{ padding: '10px' }} >
            <input
              type='text'
              name='reply'
              onChange={myChangeHandler}
              required
            /></div>

    <input type='submit' value="Reply" />
    </form>
    
     <button variant="primary" onClick={Like}>Like</button>
     </div>
  )
}


export default Posts;
```

When I replace 'pos' in the snInstance.reply() the function will work but it only posts a reply to the post of index 1. p.publisher is an integer and so is p.postCounter. I need to pass these in as arguments to these functions.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the default page reload in case of `async` requests:

pass an event object `e` to `onSubmit()` handler:

```
onSubmit={(e) => mySubmitHandler(e, p.postsCounter)}
```

And, then inside `onSubmit()`, use `e.preventDefault()`:

```
const mySubmitHandler = async (e, pos) => {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that declaring functions inline like this can reduce performance if you use this pattern everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you have to stop the default Action of the form submission using [event.preventDefault();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
<form onSubmit={(event)=>{
 event.preventDefault();
 mySubmitHandler(p.postsCounter);
}}
...>
```